# why event listener is not triggering for dynamically created radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, loops, event-listener

here is some code for a simple quiz application.An array of object is used to store the question,options and correct answer.Each question has four probable answer which are stored in an array.For those four options i created four dynamic `input radio element`. Each of the four input radio element is assigned an event listener.But somehow the event listener isn't triggering.What might be the reason for this?
for convenience i am giving the portion where actual problem lies:

```
 var setQues=(function(){

            var index=0;
            var span=document.createElement('span');
            span.setAttribute('style','color:crimson;font-weight:20px;');
            span.setAttribute('id','myspan');
            var div=document.getElementById('mydiv');
            var btn=document.getElementById('btn');


            return function (){
                div.innerHTML='';
                span.innerHTML=ques[index].title;
                div.appendChild(span);
                div.innerHTML+='</br>';
                ques[index].option.forEach(function(el,indx,arr){
                var input=document.createElement('input');
                input.setAttribute('type','radio');
                input.setAttribute('name','question');
                input.setAttribute('id',ques[index].option[indx]);

                input.value=el;
                div.appendChild(input);

                var label=document.createElement('label');
                label.setAttribute('for',ques[index].option[indx]);
                label.innerHTML=el;


                div.appendChild(label);
                input.addEventListener('change',function(e){

                    alert(this);

                });
                div.innerHTML+='</br>';

             });

             (index < ques.length-1) ? (btn.value='next',index++) : (btn.value='start quiz again',index=0);


            }})()

          document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',setQues);
```

**FULL CODE:**

```js
var ques=[
          {
      title:'who is the captain of bangladesh odi team?',
      option:['mashrafee','tamim','sakib','mushfic'],
      crctAns:'mashrafee'
    },
    {
      title:'who invented ac current?',
      option:['nicola tesla','tomas edison','henry ford','graham bell'],
      crctAns:'nicola tesla'
    },
    {  
      title:'who starred in "TRAINING DAY" movie?',
      option:['danzel washington','morgan freeman','lionerdo decaprio','chirstian bell'],
      crctAns:'danzel washington'
    }
    ];
    var setQues=(function(){
    
      var index=0;
      var span=document.createElement('span');
   span.setAttribute('style','color:crimson;font-weight:20px;');
   span.setAttribute('id','myspan');
   var div=document.getElementById('mydiv');
   var btn=document.getElementById('btn');
   
     
   return function (){
       div.innerHTML='';
       span.innerHTML=ques[index].title;
       div.appendChild(span);
    div.innerHTML+='</br>';
       ques[index].option.forEach(function(el,indx,arr){
       var input=document.createElement('input');
       input.setAttribute('type','radio');
    input.setAttribute('name','question');
    input.setAttribute('id',ques[index].option[indx]);
    
       input.value=el;
    div.appendChild(input);
    
    var label=document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for',ques[index].option[indx]);
    label.innerHTML=el;
       
    
    div.appendChild(label);
    input.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    
        alert(this);
     
    });
    div.innerHTML+='</br>';
    
    });
    
    (index < ques.length-1) ? (btn.value='next',index++) : (btn.value='start quiz again',index=0);
    
      
   }})()
    
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click',setQues);
```

```css
  #mydiv{
    background:lightblue;
    border:1px solid skyblue;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    box-shadow:-5px 0px  
    
 }
 input[type="button"]{
    cursor:pointer;
 }
 input[type='radio']{
    cursor:pointer;
 }
 label:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
 }
```

```html
<h1>quiz</h1>
<div id='mydiv' ></div>
<input type='button' value='start quiz' id='btn'>
```

Comment: You can start by removing the ** from the code so it runs

Comment: you should attach the event listener to the `radio input` before appending it to your html `DOM`

Comment: @user3138436 it works, if you replace the first `**` by  `/*` and the second one by `*/`.

Comment: @mplungjan it was for making the text bold in this site.it didn't work though .i removed it

Comment: i removed ** from my code.It was for this site to make the text bold.It was not in my actual code.Still it isn't working

Comment: I know. Also not after moving the handler to before the append

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7q81sfd0/15/

Tried adding event listeners before appending the child to the `DOM`, didn't work. Resorted to a loop, after all radio buttons were appended to the `DOM`.

```
var inputRadio = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for(var i = 0; i < inputRadio.length; i++) {
    if(inputRadio[i].type === "radio")
    {
        inputRadio[i].onchange = function() {
            console.log("clicked "+this.value);
        };                
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test that? - It does not make a change: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7q81sfd0/

Comment: Modified my answer. Hopefully, someone can enlighten us as to why the event handler doesn't work with variables.

Comment: if the code i've provided doesn't work this way then why it works? http://jsfiddle.net/hq15Lpct/

Comment: Just can't put my finger on it. The only difference i see is that of scope.

Comment: can you explain a little about the problems related to scoping?